# setIsAccessibilityElement not working in UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview, uikit, uiaccessibility

I have a plain UITableViewCell whose label I set and I also set isAccessibilityElement to FALSE. However voiceover still speaks the label when it has focus. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 8):

Set the `accessibilityElementsHidden` to YES instead.

Answer (score -1):

For UITableViewCell: You need to implement the isAccessibilityElement method of the UIAccessibility protocol in the implementation of your custom subclass.

```
- (BOOL)isAccessibilityElement{
   return NO;
}
```

For more details, go through below link: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/iPhoneAccessibility/Making_Application_Accessible/Making_Application_Accessible.html

Answer (score -1):

try this inside the cell class.

self.contentView. isAccessibilityElement = NO;